# Set the distance between labels of y-axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created the bubble plot below but as you can see I have so many names in the y axis that cannot be distinguished. How can I enlarge the distance between them in order to make them more visible?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# The dataset is provided in the gapminder library
library(gapminder)
data <- gapminder %>% filter(year=="2007") %>% dplyr::select(-year)

# Most basic bubble plot
data %>%
  arrange(desc(pop)) %>%
  mutate(country = factor(country, country)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=gdpPercap, y=country, size=pop, color=continent)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.5) +
  scale_size(range = c(.1, 24), name="Population (M)")+ facet_grid(cols = vars(continent))+ 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

[image]

Comment: There is not enough space on Y-axis, do you want to show all the labels?

Comment: Yes somehow. As it is now it is nearly useless.

Comment: @firmo23 Is it valid to drop some labels in y-axis in order to keep the same structure?

Comment: Im afraid no I cannot drop some

Comment: Can you not tradeoff plot height versus font size until it fits satisfactorily?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from showing all countries on the same axis even if you grouped by continent. You should switch `facet_grid()` for `facet_wrap()` and set `scales = "free_y"`. Then you can save your image and set the height and width to get what you want. The dimensions I used for the image below were height = 800, width = 2000.

```
data %>%
  arrange(desc(pop)) %>%
  mutate(country = factor(country, country)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=gdpPercap, y=country, size=pop, color=continent)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.5) +
  scale_size(range = c(.1, 24), name="Population (M)") + 
  facet_wrap(~ continent, nrow = 1, scales = "free_y")+ 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

[image]

Comment: I can see your thought but the labels in my original dataset are too long and with your solution the plots are not displayed at all.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest an approach where you can dodge the y-axis labels but implies that you must set the font size. You have to add `guide = guide_axis(n.dodge=2)` to `scale_y_discrete()` option. You can play around how many dodged levels you want. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# The dataset is provided in the gapminder library
library(gapminder)
data <- gapminder %>% filter(year=="2007") %>% dplyr::select(-year)

#Plot
data %>%
  arrange(desc(pop)) %>%
  mutate(country = factor(country, country)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=gdpPercap, y=country, size=pop, color=continent)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.5) +
  scale_y_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge=2))+
  scale_size(range = c(.1, 24), name="Population (M)")+ facet_grid(cols = vars(continent))+ 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=7))
```

Output:

[image]